# GMB Q&A API v1 Does not return list of answers

Tags: google-my-business-api

When making a call to the Questions endpoint (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/qanda/rest/v1/locations.questions/list) using a URL like
https://mybusinessqanda.googleapis.com/v1/locations/7588802572969590693/questions
I get back a list of questions with top answers. However when I make a call to the Answers endpoint (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/qanda/rest/v1/locations.questions.answers/list) using a URL like
https://mybusinessqanda.googleapis.com/v1/locations/7588802572969590693/questions/AIe9_BExcxslmE1rr7n5jMcadSKe_cI3ZkOvVEvqa8t0FKNXgmSYiUhM_1uJsGKdkR7rDZwgFwpFSWBONLvdDvfxs5c7gNiOk4Z6MdcNBPJyLb0wBiy8uR0Ezz2aMrE3xRIW9sIysNDK/answers
to get a list of all answers for a specific question name I keep getting the below error response:

{  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",    "status": "NOT_FOUND"  }}

If I take any of the question names from the first questions list call, the answers call always returns the above error message.

Comment: I also found this bug and reported it to the GBP API support, they're looking into it.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this issue, and already contacted their support team but no response yet from their end. Will you please post your workaround for this error if you already heard from them? Thank you

Comment: @vpriesner Where do you report GMB API support issues? It sounds like you got a reply from them.

Comment: @skyranch I did and shared this ticket with them as well. Our "workaround" for now is not migrating to the new API until this is resolved.

Comment: @NavaH This is the general support form: support.google.com/business/contact/api_default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update 3: fixed again as of April 14, 2022.

---

Update 2: this bug was reintroduced in April 2022.

---

Update: This bug was fixed yesterday (Feb 22, 2022).

---

This is a bug.

The only remediation possible right now is to continue using the GMB API v4.9 method: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.questions.answers/list

Comment: Yes we are unable to retrieve answers for given question. Not knowing whats taking so long for GMB team to fix these issues.